# Minimizing second input in scipy.minimize_scalar (with first one passed as an argument)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, minimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have defined a function that I want to minimize using `minimize_scalar`, this function `func(a,b)` has two inputs and I want to pass the first one as an argument, while default for it is the second.

Here is what I tried to do:

```py
def func(a, b):
   # do stuff
   return value

result = minimize_scalar(func, bounds=(c, d), args=(a), method="bounded", ...)
```

If I run this code it takes the argument `a` as the parameter `b` in `func(a, b)`, is it possible to do it the other way around (`a` as the parameter `a` in `func(a, b`)?
I thought that `minimize_scalar` would recognize the name of the variable but it looks like this is not possible.

Comment: Variables are not passed by 'name'.  In `args=(a,)` (note the comma, the value of `a` is passed; `minimize_scalar` just 'sees' that value, not your name.  The `minimize_scalar` docs are clear as to what order it passes the arguments.  You have to conform to its rules, not make up your own.

Comment: You'll have to either re-write the function so that it's `func(b, a)` or use `lambda x: func(a = default_value_here, x)`.

Comment: Do like this ```result = minimize_scalar(lambda b: func(a, b), bounds=(c, d), method="bounded", ...)```.